# What does "assign A to B" mean?

Tags: terminology, semantics, linguistics

If I say "assign A to B", does it mean (a) A ← B or
(b) B ← A?

In other words, is it (a) A or (b) B that is being modified?

(a) makes sense because A has responsibility over B, so A is assigned to B.

(b) makes sense because A is some object in memory that needs an owner, so object A is assigned to an owner B.

Comment: I've only ever seen usage (b).

Comment: Enough people use (a) that you need to be very careful when a sentence could be interpreted either way, but I usually see (b).

Comment: @user2357112 I'm comfortable with "assign variable `A` to have value `B`" for (a), but I prefer "assign value `A` to variable `B`" for (b).

Comment: When you assign a motive to someone, how to you interpret that? The other direction would be "set", as it "set pax to work".

Comment: But what I find terribly confusing is "A → B", which I originally interpreted as "variable `A` changes to have value `B`", despite people seemingly intending the meaning "B ← A" (in the sense of: "assign value `A` to variable `B`").

Comment: In what way is this question lacking in detail or clarity?

Comment: And why does it deserve a -1?

Comment: I avoid using the term, and when I see it being used, I infer its meaning from context.

Comment: @LoverofStructure the syntax `a -> b` is actually used in the programming languages POP2 and POP-11. Also, many assembly languages use the syntax `MOV source, dest`. It's uncommon but not that uncommon.

Comment: I think your question is fine, but perhaps you can add some information about where you have encountered the two usages.

Comment: @LoverofStructure I think I confused "assigned" with "assigned to" (see k314159's answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As can be seen in [this Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Assignment_(computer_science)), conventionally the assignment `a := b` can be described in English by both the following statements, which are equivalent/interchangeable:

1. the value `b` is assigned to `a` (or assign b to a)
2. `a` is assigned the value `b`    (or assign a the value b)

As you can see, it all depends on whether the word 'assigned' is followed by 'to'.